# how to mock patch `today` in pytest python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, patch, pytest-mock

Suppose I have a module that checks a date is today (this is a simplified code)

```
# my_module.py
import datetime


def is_today(input_date):
    return input_date == datetime.date.today()
```

I want to test this function

```
# test_my_module.py
import datetime
from unittest.mock import patch

from my_module import is_today


def test_is_today():
    cases = [
        {'input_date': datetime.date(2022, 5, 14), 'expected_output': True, 'today': datetime.date(2022, 5, 14)},
        {'input_date': datetime.date(2022, 5, 14), 'expected_output': False, 'today': datetime.date(2022, 5, 12)}
    ]
    for case in cases:
        with patch('my_module.datetime.date.today', lambda x: case['today']):
            assert is_today(case['input_date']) == case['expected_output']
```

But when I run `pytest test_my_module.py`, I get `FAILED test_my_module.py::test_is_today - TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'datetime.date'`

Any idea how to do it?

Also does anybody know how to do it with pytest-mock and which method is prefered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could patch the entire `datetime`:

```py
    for case in cases:
        class FakeDatetime:
            class date:
                def today(): return case['today']
        with patch('my_module.datetime', FakeDatetime)
```

The limitation is that you lose all other functionality of `datetime`.

Comment: generally, is this a good idea to use patch from unittest in pytest? can we do the same with pytest-mock?

Comment: Since unittest is part of the Python standard library, it should be ok to use. At least, that's what I usually do... still, someone may prove me wrong :)

Comment: This is a similar question but with a new problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71845390/how-to-partially-mock-patch-datetime-in-pytest-python

Comment: The answer to that question makes me facepalm myself :) I kinda thought we were patching the `datetime` class, but we're actually patching the entire module... this is a bit of an overkill and it would be indeed better just patch `datetime.date`.