# How to partially mock patch datetime in pytest python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, patch

Suppose I have a module that checks if an input date is today. If it is today, shows tomorrow, otherwise, returns False

```
# my_module.py
import datetime


def is_today_return_tomorrow(input_date):
    if input_date != datetime.date.today():
        return False
    return input_date + datetime.timedelta(1)
```

The purpose of this example is having a function that have both `datetime.date.today()` and `datetime.timedelta(1)` and it is a simplified code to explain the question.

Now I want to test this code using pytest.

```
# test_my_module.py
import datetime
from unittest.mock import patch

from my_module import is_today_return_tomorrow


def test_is_today():
    cases = [
        {'input_date': datetime.date(2022, 5, 14), 'expected_output': datetime.date(2022, 5, 15), 'today': datetime.date(2022, 5, 14)},
        {'input_date': datetime.date(2022, 5, 14), 'expected_output': False, 'today': datetime.date(2022, 5, 12)}
    ]
    for case in cases:
        class FakeDatetime:
            class date:
                def today(): return case['today']
        with patch('my_module.datetime', FakeDatetime)
            assert is_today_return_tomorrow(case['input_date']) == case['expected_output']
```

This is the answer explained in this question [how to mock patch `today` in pytest python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71803168/how-to-mock-patch-today-in-pytest-python)

However, there is now a problem. Because I am patching `my_module.datetime`, it no longer has `timedelta` method. How should I address this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can just patch `datetime.date` instead of the whole `datetime` module:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("input_data, expected_output, today",
                         [(datetime.date(2022, 5, 14),
                           datetime.date(2022, 5, 15),
                           datetime.date(2022, 5, 14)),
                          (datetime.date(2022, 5, 14),
                           False,
                           datetime.date(2022, 5, 12))])
def test_is_today(input_data, expected_output, today):
    with patch('my_module.datetime.date') as date:
        date.today.return_value = today
        assert is_today_return_tomorrow(input_data) == expected_output
```

This leaves other `datetime` functions like `timedelta` intact and can use them.

Note that I have replaced the iteration over test cases by standard `pytest` parametrization, as you are using `pytest` anyway.